# Transform String concatenation into String.format with parameters

Tags: intellij-idea

Is the a way to make Intellij Idea to extract concatenated strings into String that uses String.format with parameteres, like:

transform:

```
String parameter = "the parameter";

                    String message = "the parameter of the message is: "+parameter;
```

into:

```
            String parameter = "the parameter";
            String message = String.format("the parameter of the message is: %s", parameter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I found it. I thought it should be in the Refactor This/Extract menu:

[image]

Comment: where is it actually?